# Installing RD Gateway on a server with another site already in Default Web Site and listening on port 443?

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2, web facing with one website already installed.
I would like to also add the RD Gateway services to this machine since it is already accessible form the internet. However I am running into some issues when doing so.

First I am able to install RD gateway on the same default website and bind RDG and the other website to different addresses so they can have different SSL certificates. However I am unable to connect to the RD Gateway using a RDP client. I get the following error:

[image]

I found the [Following Article on how to fix this problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2008/08/30/troubleshooting-ts-gateway-connectivity-on-windows-2008-iis-7-0.aspx). However after following this advice I have the same issues.

The RDGateway and other web site ar elistenign on different IPs / site names.

However I get this message everytime I try to load the RDGateway manager [image]

Does any one have any experience with this, and how i can accomplish this?

Comment: I am looking at just deploying a new server just to run RD Gateway as the number of users vs. the amount of resources needed is very minimal. Plus Server 2012, who doesn't love that!?